# Why was this question about finding and fixing fragmented files closed?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, close-reasons

[Find Fragmented Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654016/find-fragmented-files) is a good question. It asks how to find out if a file or files are fragmented.

I had an answer, or part at least, for Windows, but can't post it now that the question is closed.

What is wrong with this question?

Comment: How do you know Windows is what the OP wants? And are you planning to just dish out code for him?

Comment: If you have a good answer you can always either a) edit Q and reopen or b) ask a better Q and self-answer

Comment: no i do not have code to dish out for fragmentation. but there are solutions online for windows and I'm sure for other languages as well. Looks like he needed to do more google work and state his goals better. hope he gets to read this before this question is deleted, as it seems the answer is getting votes but the question is drowning!

Comment: also i thought he would want a solution to tackle this from java but using different impls for diff OS, that is one of the reasons people choose java? i guessed one of the impls would be in windows

Comment: i think it should be re opened i tried but it wanted me to add 6 chars?

Answer (score 10):

It is not a good question.  It would be like me asking you "Please tell me how to write a disk defragmenter in Java."

Even if you knew how, would it be a good use of your time?  How long do you think it would take to explain it?  Is he really looking for you to explain how to do it, or is he just looking for some code to cut and paste?

Because of the existence of [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/), users on Stack Overflow are expected to demonstrate some minimal effort at solving the problem themselves.  "I can't find anything in Google" is not really a sufficient demonstration of effort.

Comment: what does a non help vampire do when his own knowledge and that of his use of a search engine not give him any result? ask on a forum or here in my experience.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @tgkprog.  That post while not spectacular doesn't seem to be a help-vampire (yet); the user had a specific issue he doesn't know the answer to.  He doesn't even ask for code in the question... admittedly I'm not a java expert so perhaps this is more complicated than I know.

Comment: I reopened the question.